# How would I do this layout in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a very specific layout in mind that I have been trying to accomplish for some time with no success. The layout I am trying to create is just to put a single JPanel, of a fixed height positioned in the vertical center of the other panel. Horizontally, it should stretch to fit the bounds of the other.

Again, the needs are for it to be:

1. Two JPanels, one placed inside the other
2. The inner panel should have a static height
3. The inner panel should be vertically centered
4. The inner panel should horizontally stretch to meet the sides of the outer panel.

The following is a picture of an example of this:
[image]

Per several people's requests for me to post my code which doesn't work:

```
JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
frmPhoneClicker.getContentPane().add(MainPanel);
MainPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[984px]", "[165px]"));


Panel subPanel = new JPanel();
subPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
MainPanel.add(subPanel, "cell 0 0 1 1,growx,aligny center");
```

Comment: Try a 3rd party layout manager like MigLayout. That should provide all you need. If you want to use a built-in layout manager you could try [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

Comment: @Thomas I tried that however I could not figure out how to make the one cell I got it to work in to take up the entire space of the outer panel.

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard, just let the inner panel grow horizontally but not vertically. And don't set any maximum width etc. If it doesn't work you might want to show some code.

Comment: *"I have been trying to accomplish for some time"* Show us your best attempt in the form of a [mcve]. BTW - I'd use a `GridBagLayout` for this requirement..

Comment: @AndrewThompson there you go

Comment: @ArcticLord I added it

Comment: Code snippets are not an MCVE! Minus one for not reading the link.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Would you rather me add my entire project with the build path? I believe I followed the structure rather well, those lines were A: Minimal (I took out what was not needed), B: Complete (I added all that was needed to allow people to understand and recreate the problem), and C: Verifiable (Using that code you can recreate the problem... if you had read my entire post you would see that I clearly defined the issue). Furthermore, where in the MCVE document linked does it state that code snippets are "not allowed"?

Comment: *"B: Complete (I added all that was needed to allow people to understand and recreate the problem),"* Complete needs imports and a `main(String[])` method to put it on-screen. If it is an MCVE of a run-time problem, it needs to compile cleanly as copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need to learn more about Layouts in your case [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) would be helpful. But here you go:

```
// your Panels
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // use GridBagLayout with mainPanel
subPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (0,165)); // use a preferred height for the subPanel
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints(); // your gridBagLayout Constraints
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // stretch subPanel horizontal
c.weightx = 1.0; // with 100% of screen
mainPanel.add(subPanel,c); // add sub to mainPanel with the constraints
```

Comment: ArcticLord, Thank you so much for your very helpful answer. I agree, I do need to learn more about Layouts. While I am not new to Java I am mostly new to Swing. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

A complete working example with colors to follow your scheme:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class testPanel extends JFrame{

    public testPanel() {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        this.setSize(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight * 2 / 3);

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        this.setUndecorated(false);

        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        outerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        innerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        innerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (0,300));

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;//Size
        outerPanel.add(innerPanel, c);

        this.add(outerPanel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Please note that if the containing window size goes below the size of the `innerPanel`, then the fixed height will not apply anymore.